# How to get rid of bubble from UITextField?

Tags: swift, forms

I am trying to create a form for a user to input data.  My idea was to make it a TableViewController, and create some cells for it.

How can I make a form that looks like Apple's apps?

See here from the Health App by Apple(**ignore the red arrows**):

[image]

Would the way I described above be the correct way of achieving this interface look?  Is there a framework that everyone uses that I am not aware of for creating forms?

I don't want the text fields to look like bubbles:

[image]

Comment: For your question about a forms framework, [Eureka](https://eurekacommunity.github.io), seems good for this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Using Storyboards

[image: Attributes]

You can change the border style by selecting a `UITextField` and then in the attributes inspector select the desired border style.

#### Using Code

```
textField.borderStyle = .none

textField.borderStyle = .bezel

textField.borderStyle = .line

textField.borderStyle = .roundedRect
```

---

You can also create a custom class of `UITextField` if these border styles don't suit your needs.

From your question, I think you just want the `none` border style.